# is xss possible without < if so how?

Tags: filter, xss

if only < is filtered, is xss possible? In the context that you post a comment on a site and it is then displayed to users. If so, i haven't seen any such vectors and i'd love to see how it's possible.

Comment: You've been posting duplicates of your questions from your other, presumably question-banned account.

Answer (score 1):

Sure; while exploits require knowing *how* the data is used, here is a counter example showing an "XSS attack" that doesn't require using `<`. In this case the server incorrectly built a JavaScript code block, say with `var post = '$foo';` - oops!

```
<script>
    var post = 'Imagine this was set ';HackIt();'on the server';
    ShowPost(post);
</script>
```

(The malicious data was `Imagine this was set ';HackIt();'on the server`.)

Comment: no, that's a very unlikely chance that wouldn't work on the context i meant, imagine it as this comment feature on stackoverflow, the server filters out the < character, what xss vector is possible?

Comment: @yoman This is a realistic avenue of injecting data. If a specific case is imagined, then present it along with *actual* code of its usage.